# I need these objects in this array to move at random speeds.

Tags: javascript, oop

This is a link to my github. https://github.com/inventive-dev217/arcade-game . I need for the items in my allEnemies array to move at random speeds. Right now they are all moving at the same speed. Any ideas how to implement this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include code you are asking about in the question, not in a link that will undoubtedly go stale once someone answers the question for you, thereby making this question useless for anyone else in the future - the keyword to your answer is `random` - if only javascript had some sort of random number generator

Comment: Though, to be fair, you can see thousands of incarnations of this code on github alone

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not an expert in JS, but something like this should work :

```
var Enemy = function(x, y) {
// Variables applied to each of our instances go here,
// we've provided one for you to get started
// The image/sprite for our enemies, this uses
// a helper we've provided to easily load images
this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * MaxSpeedValue) + MinSpeedValue;
```

}